# With ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers, does the Process method Call ProcessAsync or the other way?

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I can't find the source code for the TagHelper method in asp.net MVC source.  I'm trying to understand the relationship between the two. I notice that the ITagHelper interface only requires ProcessAsync so I'm thinking that Process must call ProcessAsync somehow but I'd like to find that in the source so I better understand.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.itaghelper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are seeing the `Process` method that actually comes from [`TagHelper`](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime/TagHelpers/TagHelper.cs) which implements the [`ITagHelper`](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime/TagHelpers/ITagHelper.cs) interface and adds `Process` as a virtual method. The XML comment says:

> Synchronously executes the TagHelper with the given context and output.

So it's entirely up to the tag helper how to implement those methods. One option, as you suggest, would be for one to call the other. The implementation is entirely up to the component itself. However, the XML comments against the async method state this:

> ProcessAsync: By default this calls into `Process`

And [the code](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime/TagHelpers/TagHelper.cs#L54) shows this to be how it works:

```cs
public virtual Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    Process(context, output);
    return TaskCache.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: could you post a link to the processAsync code you posted.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks @DavidG, did not notice the hyperlink. Also, thanks for letting me know where (razor view engine).  That makes sense.